# asp.net mvc - routetable catching partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a rule defined as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "DefaultVideo",                                              // Route name
                "{action}/{id}/{title}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", title = "" },
                new { id = new IDConstraint() });
```

However, this is catching partialview codes too,  that is strictly supposed to be used as partial views. How do I distinguish that in my code that not to catch code meant for partialview as routing thing?

Comment: @progtick, could you explain in a little more detail what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net mvc partial view behaved exactly like views in this that your action can return they both as well.

Answer (score 0):

Routing has nothing to do with views and partial views. Controller is the boss who decides what will be returned.

And try to clarify your question.